# Fitting largest circle in free area in image with distributed particle

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, geometry, particles

I am working on images to detect and fit the largest possible circle in any of the free areas of an image containing distributed particles:[image: 1]

(able to detect the location of particle).

One direction is to define a circle touching any 3-point combination, checking if the circle is empty, then finding the largest circle among all empty circles. However, it leads to a huge number of combination i.e. `C(n,3)`, where `n` is the total number of particles in the image.

I would appreciate if anyone can provide me any hint or alternate method that I can explore.

Comment: I assume you have a radius limit, right? Also I assume you mean the smallest circle with at least `n` particles inside it?else the largest circle is `r=Inf`.   Or do you mean largest circle containing maximum `n` particles?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I believe he means the largest circle _without_ any particles in it

Comment: @AnderBiguri I think he means the largest circle which can fit in the space *without* containing any points...

Comment: @Wolfie hum... I misinterpreted the "3 points" statement

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I think the proposed algorithm was: 1) Get all triplets of points. 2) Define circles using these sets of 3 points (this will be unique). 3) Discard circles containing points. 4) Find the largest remaining circle. The problem being there are *many* triplets, so the algorithm is slow.

Comment: @DanielAlder thanks, your interpretation of the problem is correct and is the same I what to inquire about

Comment: @Wolfie thanks, your interpretation of the problem is correct and is the same I what to inquire about and your explanation of the algorithm is correct ( what I am working on currently)

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes i mean the largest circle which can fit in the space without containing any points...

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks for the suggestion. I will try and work with Voronoi triangulation or dilation in image processing  to see if it can solve my problem

Comment: @TarunKumarAgrawal does my answer work? Do you need more help?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Many thanks for the solution. It works fine for my problem

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Lets do some maths my friend, as maths will always get to the end!

Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, a Voronoi diagram is a partitioning of a plane into
>   regions based on distance to points in a specific subset of the plane.

For example:

```
rng(1)
x=rand(1,100)*5;
y=rand(1,100)*5;


voronoi(x,y);
```

[image]

The nice thing about this diagram is that if you notice, all the edges/vertices of those blue areas are all to equal distance to the points around them. Thus, if we know the location of the vertices, and compute the distances to the closest points, then we can choose the vertex with highest distance as our center of the circle.

Interestingly, the edges of a Voronoi regions are also defined as the circumcenters of the triangles generated by a Delaunay triangulation.

So if we compute the Delaunay triangulation of the area, and their circumcenters

```
dt=delaunayTriangulation([x;y].');
cc=circumcenter(dt); %voronoi edges
```

And compute the distances between the circumcenters and any of the points that define each triangle:

```
for ii=1:size(cc,1)
    if cc(ii,1)>0 && cc(ii,1)<5 && cc(ii,2)>0 && cc(ii,2)<5
    point=dt.Points(dt.ConnectivityList(ii,1),:); %the first one, or any other (they are the same distance)
    distance(ii)=sqrt((cc(ii,1)-point(1)).^2+(cc(ii,2)-point(2)).^2);
    end
end
```

Then we have the center (`cc`) and radius (`distance`) of all possible circles that have no point inside them. We just need the biggest one!

```
[r,ind]=max(distance); %Tada!
```

Now lets plot

```
hold on

ang=0:0.01:2*pi; 
xp=r*cos(ang);
yp=r*sin(ang);

point=cc(ind,:);

voronoi(x,y)
triplot(dt,'color','r','linestyle',':')
plot(point(1)+xp,point(2)+yp,'k');
plot(point(1),point(2),'g.','markersize',20);
```

[image]

Notice how the center of the circle is on one vertex of the Voronoi diagram.

---

**NOTE**: this will find the center inside [0-5],[0-5]. you can easily modify it to change this constrain. You can also try to find the circle that fits on its entirety inside the interested area (as opposed to just the center). This would require a small addition in the end where the maximum is obtained.

Comment: Pretty special answer, good work Ander. One question: you use the function `delaunayTriangulation`... is this a custom function? Why not use Matlab's built in `delaunay`?

Comment: @Wolfie [It is not a custom function!](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation-class.html)

Comment: Ah my Googling skills need sharpening! For others' reference, the difference is that `delaunay` is a function, whilst `delaunayTriangulation` is a class with "many methods that are useful for developing triangulation-based algorithms". For more info, see https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/delaunay-triangulation.html

Comment: An alternative (but I think equivalent) method would be to compute the distance transform of the image (using bwdist). The largest circle will then be centred on the pixel with the largest value, with the radius equal to that value.

Comment: @GuyRT Indeed. I think this method has the advantage of working in continuous space. The result does not need to be a integer pixel index.

Comment: Whoa... this seems like a super-tricky solution. I like it. +1. How computationally efficient is this method?

Comment: @Delioth takes virtually no time in my PC

Comment: I will warn you that it will sometimes place the circle outside the boundaries of the image, so something to fix that might be helpful.  I tried it with rng(0) through rng(10), and at least one was completely out of bounds, and a couple more were partially out of bounds.

Comment: @fyrepenguin If you read carefully, this answer ends with a disclaimer about that. The centre of the circle can not be out of bounds (there is an explicit `if` condition) but the circle can be partly out of bounds. Easy to fix, i desired.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I guess I didn't read it properly, mea culpa. However, I was testing it out, and I ended up with a circle centered around -11 or so on the x axis.  I don't have a computer with MATLAB nearby right now, so I can't show you an image of what I'm talking about, unfortunately.

Comment: @fyrepenguin It did happen to me before, that is why I added the `if`. Maybe I am missing something. Will try it again tomorrow if I can.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I do see that if statement now.  I am unsure of why it was behaving oddly for me, I can check tomorrow as well. This was a really nifty question and answer though.

Comment: @Delioth The method is O(nlog(n)). I am unaware of any faster solution to this problem - this is generally the way of solving it. Interestingly, inverse problem (find minimum circle containing all points) can be solved in O(n).

Comment: You require a few extra checks for a completely general solution. This one will find the max circle touching 3 points. But the biggest circle with center in (0,5) might touch just one or 2. Or, when the whole circle is confined to (0,5), the biggest one might touch 2 edges and 1 point (or 2 points and 1 edge).

Comment: @ZizyArcher Yes is if the problem is that the circle is in its entirety inside the area. As it was not asked explicitly and in OPs data, the centre of the biggest circle is in a corner of the image (see rahnema's answer), this seems to work. I may (if I have some time) take the time to add that up, now that this answer has blown out of proportion

Answer (score 25):

I'd like to propose another solution based on a grid search with refinement. It's not as advanced as Ander's or as short as rahnema1's, but it *should* be very easy to follow and understand. Also, it runs quite fast.

The algorithm contains several stages:

1. We generate an evenly-spaced grid.
2. We find the minimal distances of points in the grid to all provided points.
3. We discard all points whose distances are below a certain percentile (e.g. 95th).
4. We choose the region which contains the largest distance (this should contain the correct center if my initial grid is fine enough).
5. We create a new meshgrid around the chosen region and find distances again (this part is clearly sub-optimal, because the distances are computed to all points, including far and irrelevant ones).
6. We iterate the refinement within the region, while keeping an eye on the variance of the top 5% of values -> if it drops below some preset threshold we break.

Several notes:

- I have made the assumption that circles cannot go beyond the scattered points' extent (i.e. the bounding square of the scatter acts as an "invisible wall").
- The appropriate percentile depends on how fine the initial grid is. This will also affect the amount of `while` iterations, and the optimal initial value for `cnt`.

```
function [xBest,yBest,R] = q42806059
rng(1)
x=rand(1,100)*5;
y=rand(1,100)*5;

%% Find the approximate region(s) where there exists a point farthest from all the rest:
xExtent = linspace(min(x),max(x),numel(x)); 
yExtent = linspace(min(y),max(y),numel(y)).';
% Create a grid:
[XX,YY] = meshgrid(xExtent,yExtent);
% Compute pairwise distance from grid points to free points:
D = reshape(min(pdist2([XX(:),YY(:)],[x(:),y(:)]),[],2),size(XX));
% Intermediate plot:
% figure(); plot(x,y,'.k'); hold on; contour(XX,YY,D); axis square; grid on;
% Remove irrelevant candidates:
D(D<prctile(D(:),95)) = NaN;
D(D > xExtent | D > yExtent | D > yExtent(end)-yExtent | D > xExtent(end)-xExtent) = NaN;
%% Keep only the region with the largest distance
L = bwlabel(~isnan(D));
[~,I] = max(table2array(regionprops('table',L,D,'MaxIntensity')));
D(L~=I) = NaN;
% surf(XX,YY,D,'EdgeColor','interp','FaceColor','interp');
%% Iterate until sufficient precision:
xExtent = xExtent(~isnan(min(D,[],1,'omitnan')));
yExtent = yExtent(~isnan(min(D,[],2,'omitnan')));
cnt = 1; % increase or decrease according to the nature of the problem
while true
  % Same ideas as above, so no explanations:
  xExtent = linspace(xExtent(1),xExtent(end),20); 
  yExtent = linspace(yExtent(1),yExtent(end),20).'; 
  [XX,YY] = meshgrid(xExtent,yExtent);
  D = reshape(min(pdist2([XX(:),YY(:)],[x(:),y(:)]),[],2),size(XX));
  D(D<prctile(D(:),95)) = NaN;
  I = find(D == max(D(:)));
  xBest = XX(I);
  yBest = YY(I);  
  if nanvar(D(:)) < 1E-10 || cnt == 10
    R = D(I);
    break
  end
  xExtent = (1+[-1 +1]*10^-cnt)*xBest;
  yExtent = (1+[-1 +1]*10^-cnt)*yBest;
  cnt = cnt+1;
end
% Finally:
% rectangle('Position',[xBest-R,yBest-R,2*R,2*R],'Curvature',[1 1],'EdgeColor','r');
```

The result I'm getting for Ander's example data is `[x,y,r] = [0.7832, 2.0694, 0.7815]` (which is the same). The execution time is about half of Ander's solution.

#### Here are the intermediate plots:

Contour of the largest (clear) distance from a point to the set of all provided points:

[image: Distances from existing points]

After considering distance from the boundary, keeping only the top 5% of distant points, and considering only the region which contains the largest distance (the piece of surface represents the kept values):

[image: After keeping the largest region]

And finally:
[image: Showing the found circle]

Comment: eh, your plots are nicer than mine!

Comment: @AnderBiguri Nah, don't worry... just look at the version before the edit :)

Comment: @Dev-iL besides the practical application, the plots look awesome!

Answer (score 14):

You can use [bwdist](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) from Image Processing Toolbox to compute the distance transform of the image. This can be regarded as a method to create voronoi diagram that well explained in @AnderBiguri's answer.

```
img = imread('AbmxL.jpg');
%convert the image to a binary image
points = img(:,:,3)<200;
%compute the distance transform of the binary image
dist = bwdist(points);
%find the circle that has maximum radius
radius = max(dist(:));
%find position of the circle
[x y] = find(dist == radius);
imshow(dist,[]);
hold on
plot(y,x,'ro');
```

[image]

Comment: You should use the same data as me so we can compare better! The results of `bwdist` look very trippy

Comment: You know you can use URLs with `imread`, right? i.e. this works: `img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbmxL.jpg');`

Comment: @AnderBiguri I used data from the question. Since the task is image processing I think you should apply your method on the image.

Comment: @Dev-iL [I can not see or directly download attached images!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291813/352728)

Comment: @rahnema1 yeah sorry, I did not realise. Great answer!

Answer (score 14):

The fact that this problem can be solved using a "direct search" (as can be seen in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42822810/3372061)) means one can look at this as a [global optimization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/index.html) problem. There exist various ways to solve such problems, each appropriate for certain scenarios. Out of my personal curiosity I have decided to solve this using a **genetic algorithm**.

Generally speaking, such an algorithm requires us to think of the solution as a set of "genes" subject to "evolution" under a certain "fitness function". As it happens, it's quite easy to identify the genes and the fitness function in this problem:

- Genes: `x` , `y`, `r`.
- Fitness function: technically, maximum area of circle, but this is equivalent to the maximum `r` (or minimum `-r`, since the algorithm requires a function to *minimize*).
- Special constraint - if `r` is larger than the euclidean distance to the closest of the provided points (that is, the circle contains a point), the organism "dies".

Below is a basic implementation of such an algorithm ("*basic*" because it's completely unoptimized, and there is lot of room for optimization<sup><sup>no pun intended</sup></sup> in this problem).

```
function [x,y,r] = q42806059b(cloudOfPoints)
% Problem setup
if nargin == 0
  rng(1)
  cloudOfPoints = rand(100,2)*5; % equivalent to Ander's initialization.
end
%{
figure(); plot(cloudOfPoints(:,1),cloudOfPoints(:,2),'.w'); hold on; axis square;
set(gca,'Color','k'); plot(0.7832,2.0694,'ro'); plot(0.7832,2.0694,'r*');
%}
nVariables = 3;
options = optimoptions(@ga,'UseVectorized',true,'CreationFcn',@gacreationuniform,...
                       'PopulationSize',1000);

S = max(cloudOfPoints,[],1); L = min(cloudOfPoints,[],1); % Find geometric bounds:
% In R2017a: use [S,L] = bounds(cloudOfPoints,1);

% Here we also define distance-from-boundary constraints.
g = ga(@(g)vectorized_fitness(g,cloudOfPoints,[L;S]), nVariables,...
       [],[], [],[], [L 0],[S min(S-L)], [], options);
x = g(1); y = g(2); r = g(3);
%{
plot(x,y,'ro'); plot(x,y,'r*'); 
rectangle('Position',[x-r,y-r,2*r,2*r],'Curvature',[1 1],'EdgeColor','r'); 
%}

function f = vectorized_fitness(genes,pts,extent)
% genes = [x,y,r]
% extent = [Xmin Ymin; Xmax Ymax]
% f, the fitness, is the largest radius.
f = min(pdist2(genes(:,1:2), pts, 'euclidean'), [], 2);
% Instant death if circle contains a point:
f( f < genes(:,3) ) = Inf;
% Instant death if circle is too close to boundary:
f( any( genes(:,3) > genes(:,1:2) - extent(1,:) | ...
        genes(:,3) > extent(2,:) - genes(:,1:2), 2) ) = Inf;
% Note: this condition may possibly be specified using the A,b inputs of ga().
f(isfinite(f)) = -genes(isfinite(f),3);
%DEBUG: 
%{
     scatter(genes(:,1),genes(:,2),10 ,[0, .447, .741] ,'o'); % All
 z = ~isfinite(f); scatter(genes(z,1),genes(z,2),30,'r','x'); % Killed
 z =  isfinite(f); scatter(genes(z,1),genes(z,2),30,'g','h'); % Surviving
 [~,I] = sort(f); scatter(genes(I(1:5),1),genes(I(1:5),2),30,'y','p'); % Elite
%}
```

And here's a "time-lapse" plot of 47 generations of a typical run:

[image: Time lapse]

(Where blue points are the current generation, red crosses are "insta-killed"  organisms, green hexagrams are the "non-insta-killed" organisms, and the red circle marks the destination).

Comment: While this approach seems just an exercise to the reader (meaning its probably better to use the others, including yours), man this is so cool! That gif :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm not used to image processing, so it's just an Idea:

Implement something like a gaussian filter (blur) which transforms each particle (pixels) to a round gradiant with r=image_size (all of them overlapping). This way, you should get a picture where the most white pixels should be the best results. Unfortunately, the demonstration in gimp failed because the extreme blurring made the dots disappearing.

Alternatively, you could incrementelly extend all existing pixels by marking all neighbour pixels in an area (example: r=4), the pixels left would be the same result (those with the biggest distance to any pixel)

Comment: This is a good start, but in the end, image processing has the pixel size limitation. There will always be a minimum error of 1*pixel size

Comment: Anyway, this approach is not comparable (=far beyond) to what @AnderBiguri answered :-P